# "getaddrinfo failed" when connecting to SSH/SFTP server with Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, sftp, paramiko

> socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

```
import paramiko
ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh_client.connect(hostname="10.198.2.217:22", username="tester", password="password")
ftp_client=ssh_client.open_sftp()
ftp_client.put('C:/Upload/2.txt', 'C:/sftp/data/')
ftp_client.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

`hostname` parameter of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) should contain a **hostname** only (or in your case an IP address).

A port goes to `port` parameter. Though as you are using the default SSH/SFTP port 22, there's no need to specify it.

```
ssh_client.connect(hostname="10.198.2.217", username="tester", password="password")
```