# Unable to Connect to SFTP through paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, rsa, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to establish a connection with an SFTP with paramiko. I was able to generate the known_hosts file in my local system by using

```
ssh my.domain.com
```

The resultant file has both the host and its IP in the first line of known_hosts, like

```
my.domain.com,xx.xx.xxx.xx ...
```

When I try to connect through paramiko,

```
host, port = 'my.domain.com,xx.xx.xxx.xx', 22
user, pwd = "xyz", "abc"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(host, port, username=user, password=pwd)
```

I get the error

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

After looking this up, the solutions were to [not mention user in host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301378/getaddrinfo-error-when-trying-to-establish-an-ssh-connection-using-python-para) or [add port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493296/getaddrinfo-failed-when-connecting-to-ssh-sftp-server-with-paramiko), etc. But I'm still not able to connect. I tried removing `my.domain.com` from both the Python code and known_hosts file,

```
host, port = 'xx.xx.xxx.xx', 22  
user, pwd = "xyz", "abc"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(host, port, username=user, password=pwd)
```

but that didn't work. I tried removing `xx.xx.xxx.xx` from both the Python code and known_hosts file,

```
host, port = 'xx.xx.xxx.xx', 22
user, pwd = "xyz", "abc"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(host, port, username=user, password=pwd)
```

but that didn't work either.

How do I connect to my SFTP?

Comment: You should use the domain name or ip address in `host`, but not both. In that second case, "but that didn't work either" ... is it the same error? Put my.domain.com back to the know hosts file. Add `ssh.load_system_host_keys()` before the connect and do that last example again. Does it work?

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks a ton! I was starting to get so annoyed by this!! Your tip made the code work. When I removed either of the IP or domain, it gave the error that host not found in known hosts. Anyways, now its working all thanks to your help!

Answer (score 0):

As resolved by @tdalaney in the comments. I edited the `known_hosts` file to only specify the domain name and added `ssh.load_system_host_keys()` before the `connect` method.